# bigquery - filter out unique results only

Tags: unique, google-bigquery

My database looks the following:

```
Entry-Key     Name     Surname     Age
10a           Smith    Alex        35
11b           Finn     John        41
10a           Smith    Al          35
10c           Finn     Berta       28
11b           Fin      John        41
```

I need to get unique rows out of it. **Group by** does not work properly since sometimes there are inaccuracies in Name/Surname columns.

I thought to group by just the Entry-Keys and then find the first appearance of the Key in the table and take only this row. I know how to do it in Excel but since the database has some 100,000 lines Excel is not a real option.

the idea is to get finally this table:

```
10a           Smith    Alex        35
11b           Finn     John        41
12c           Finn     Berta       28
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your logic you can do the below query:

```
select key, first(name), first(surname), first(age) from 
(select '10a' as key,           'Smith' as name,    'Alex' as surname,        35 as age),
(select '11b' as key,           'Finn' as name,     'John' as surname,        41 as age),
(select '10a' as key,           'Smith' as name,    'Al' as surname,          35 as age),
(select '10c' as key,           'Finn' as name,     'Berta' as surname,       28 as age),
(select '11b' as key,           'Fin' as name,      'John' as surname,        41 as age),
group by key
```

This returns:

```
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+---+
| Row | key |  f0_  |  f1_  | f2_ |   |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+---+
|   1 | 10a | Smith | Alex  |  35 |   |
|   2 | 11b | Finn  | John  |  41 |   |
|   3 | 10c | Finn  | Berta |  28 |   |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+---+
```

Comment: Note, that FIRST() in this context is equivalent to ANY(), since GROUP BY doesn't guarantee any particular order, and order of keys may change from query to query.